# After asking the user for how many questions they want, how can I get my code to show that number of random problems?

Tags: java, loops

I need to first ask the user to input how many problems they want to do. Then generate the first, then the second after they answer the first and so on.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number1 = (int) (Math.random() * 40 + 10), number2 = (int) (Math.random() * 40 + 10), uanswer, ianswer, counter, icounter,
            acounter, counter1, ui, aacounter, bcounter;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many problems do you want to do?");
    ui = input.nextInt();

    counter = 1;
    icounter = 1;

    acounter = counter + icounter;
    {
        System.out.print("What is " + number1 + " + " + number2 + "? ");
    }
    uanswer = input.nextInt();

    ianswer = number1 + number2;

    while (counter < 10000 && icounter < 1000 && acounter < 1000 && number1
            + number2 != uanswer) {

        System.out.println("Incorrect, the answer is "
                + ianswer + ", " + icounter + " out of " + icounter + " incorrect. Try again?");
        icounter++;
        acounter++;
        uanswer = input.nextInt();

    }
    if (ianswer == ianswer) {
        aacounter = acounter - 1;
        bcounter = icounter - 1;
        System.out.println("Correct, the answer is " + ianswer
                + ", " + counter + " out of " + aacounter + " correct, "
                + bcounter + " out of " + aacounter + " incorrect.");

    }

}
```

With my current code, I only see one problem, even though I asked for 2 or more problems at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `loop` around this statement:

```
System.out.print("What is " + number1 + " + " + number2 + "? ");
```

like:

```
for(int i=0; i<ui; i++){
    System.out.print("What is " + number1 + " + " + number2 + "? ");
    ...
```

Comment: That is just showing the same 3 problems. I need it to show the first problem and then, answer, next problem, answer, and so on depending how many questions the user wants.

Comment: The answer helps as such. Logic: for loop -> problem -> answer -> for loop -> problem... Just add all your statements for problem and answer inside the loop.